# Python logging conf can't be load in the submodule

Tags: python, logging, config

I'm trying to create a logging in my project, and I made a small logger example for practice. However I run into a problem when I try logging through submodules.

When I run the `submodule1.py`:

```py
import logging
import logging.config
import time
import os

dirname = os.path.dirname(__file__)
filename = os.path.realpath(os.path.join(dirname,'..','config','logging.conf'))
print(filename)
logging.config.fileConfig(filename, disable_existing_loggers=False)

logger=logging.getLogger('submodule1')

def from_sub1():
    logger.debug("Debug message from submodule1")
    logger.error("Error message from submodule1")

from_sub1()
```

It works fine, but when I try to run the `main.py`:

```py
import logging
import logging.config
import submodules.submodule1 as submodule1
import os
import sys

dirname = os.path.dirname(__file__)
filename = os.path.join(dirname, 'config','logger.conf')
logging.config.fileConfig(filename, disable_existing_loggers=False)

logger=logging.getLogger('main')

logger.critical('Critical message from main')
submodule1.from_sub1()
```

I got an error:

```
    Exception has occurred: FileNotFoundError
    [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Camera_Platform\\test_scripts\\.vscode\\log\\main.log'
```

It happens since I moved the modules and the configuration to different folders:

```
    SystemLogger_Example
        |_main.py
        |_config
           |_logging.conf
        |_log (I save the log files here)
        |_submodules
           |_submodule1.py
```

My `logging.conf`:

```
\[loggers\]
keys=root, main, submodule1, submodule2

\[handlers\]
keys=mainHandler, ErrorHandler, debugHandler, submodule1Handler, submodule2Handler

\[formatters\]
keys=baseformat, jsonformat

\[logger_root\]
level=DEBUG
handlers=mainHandler, ErrorHandler, debugHandler, submodule1Handler, submodule2Handler

\[logger_main\]
level=DEBUG
handlers=mainHandler, ErrorHandler
qualname=main
propagate=0

\[logger_submodule1\]
level=DEBUG
handlers=mainHandler, ErrorHandler, submodule1Handler
qualname=submodule1
propagate=0

\[logger_submodule2\]
level=DEBUG
handlers=mainHandler, ErrorHandler, submodule2Handler
qualname=submodule2
propagate=0

\[handler_mainHandler\]
class=logging.FileHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=jsonformat
args=(os.path.realpath(os.path.join(sys.path\[0\],'..','log','main.log')),'w',)

\[handler_submodule1Handler\]
class=logging.FileHandler
level=INFO
formatter=baseformat
args=(os.path.join(sys.path\[0\],'..','log','submodule1.log'),'w',)

\[handler_submodule2Handler\]
class=logging.FileHandler
level=INFO
formatter=baseformat
args=(os.path.join(sys.path\[0\],'..','log','submodule2.log'),'w',)

\[handler_ErrorHandler\]
class=logging.FileHandler
level=ERROR
formatter=baseformat
args=(os.path.join(sys.path\[0\],'..','log','ERROR.log'),'w',)

\[handler_debugHandler\]
class=logging.FileHandler
level=ERROR
formatter=baseformat
args=(os.path.join(sys.path\[0\],'..','log','debug.log'),'w',)

\[formatter_baseformat\]
format=%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s

\[formatter_jsonformat\]
class = pythonjsonlogger.jsonlogger.JsonFormatter
format=%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s
```

Version=3.9.1

Comment: Is there `__init__.py` file in submodule directory?

Comment: I added it, and tried again, but I got, the same result.